# "No installable Kernel was found in the defined APT sources"

Tags: installation, 10.04, kernel

I'm trying to install an old `ubuntu-10.04.4-server-amd64.iso` on a custom machine, which uses a `vortex86` processor. The installation works fine, but it can't install a kernel.

> "No installable Kernel was found in the defined APT sources"

I continued and finished the installation without installing a kernel.

Then I tried to switch to a virtual shell for executing `apt-install linux-image-generic` ([seen in this guide](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1550587)), but there's no package named so. The fun story is that with the `lubuntu-10.04-desktop-i386.iso` everything works well with the i386 image...! Now I've got a base system without kernel.

I've also got a custom package from the vendor: [linux-image-2.6.34.10-vortex86-sg_1.3_i386.deb](http://download.epatec.net/PMX_Panel_PC/linux-image-2.6.34.10-vortex86-sg_1.3_i386.deb).
But, there's a way to install this kernel without booting (like starting a live and chrooting on the target system)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the 64 bit installer even booted up, since it seems this is only a 32 bit cpu.  You said the 32 bit version works, so stick with that.